# Ubuntu stuck at american megatrend

Tags: 20.04, display, startup, bios

Yesterday, my pc was working perfect. But from today morning, it stuck at the startup window of American Megatrends.

[stuck display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4GQg.jpg)

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like there are some instructions on your screen, why don't you read them, I can't because of the bad quality of your photo.

Comment: @mook765 these are simple instruction. Have a look at this image: Not any key is working

https://www.ami.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/top-three-keys-used-to-enter-uefi-bios-setup_01.jpg

Comment: I think you have a hardware problem.

Comment: did you check out hard disk boot order from your bios settings? if not, please make your hard disk #1

Comment: @osakacjupiter how may I found it?

Comment: This is stuck at your bios, Ubuntu did not start yet. Sorry, but off topic here.

Comment: @pLumo any solution?

Comment: In this BIOS, go to "Boot" menu and then in "Boot Device Priority". To boot from hard disk, select your hard disk for the "1st Boot Device" option. Finally, press the F10 key (Save and Exit) and then confirm by pressing the "Y" key, if necessary.